# Kubernetes with flannel: CNI config uninitialized

Tags: kubernetes, flannel, cni

I am trying to setup a Kubernetes cluster on local machines. Bare metal. No OpenStack, No Maas or something.

After `kubeadm init ...` on the master node, `kubeadm join ...` on the slave nodes and [applying flannel](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml) at the master I get the message from the slaves:

> runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized

Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong or missed any steps?
Should flannel be applied to all the slave nodes as well? If yes, they do not have a `admin.conf`...

PS. All the nodes do not have internet access. That means all files have to be copied manually via ssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the missing internet connection. After loading the Docker images manually to the worker nodes they appear to be ready.

Unfortunately I did not found a helpful error message around this.

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem cause by kuberadm first init coredns but not init flannel,so it throw "network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized".
Solution:
1. Install flannel by `kubectl -n kube-system apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/bc79dd1505b0c8681ece4de4c0d86c5cd2643275/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml`
2. Reset the coredns pod
`kubectl delete coredns-xx-xx`
3. Then run `kubectl get pods` to see if it works.

if you see this error "cni0" already has an IP address different from 10.244.1.1/24".
follow this:

```
ifconfig  cni0 down
brctl delbr cni0
ip link delete flannel.1
```

if you see this error "Back-off restarting failed container", and you can get the log by

```
root@master:/home/moonx/yaml# kubectl logs coredns-86c58d9df4-x6m9w -n=kube-system
.:53
2019-01-22T08:19:38.255Z [INFO] CoreDNS-1.2.6
2019-01-22T08:19:38.255Z [INFO] linux/amd64, go1.11.2, 756749c
CoreDNS-1.2.6
linux/amd64, go1.11.2, 756749c
 [INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = f65c4821c8a9b7b5eb30fa4fbc167769
 [FATAL] plugin/loop: Forwarding loop detected in "." zone. Exiting. See https://coredns.io/plugins/loop#troubleshooting. Probe query: "HINFO 1599094102175870692.6819166615156126341.".
```

Then you can see the file "/etc/resolv.conf" on the failed node, if the nameserver is localhost there will be a loopback.Change to:

```
#nameserver 127.0.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually flannel is deployed as daemonset. Meaning on all worker nodes.

Comment: I applyed https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml on the master. Do you mean then it gets deployed the other nodes automatically? Or do you have to apply this manually to all nodes?